# Selected filter should be show in active filter list

Tags: php, html

I have a website showing some products. Like many other websites, I am trying to filters the results. I have a color filter. I am showing the color thumbnails and on selecting any color thumbnail, the page will redirect and load products with that color. Now I have an extra `<div>` where I am showing the thumbnails from the active colors. So once an user selects a color thumbnail, it should reload the page with the color filtered products and the selected thumbnail should be visible in the active filter `div`. How can I do that?

Following is my code:

```
<?
    $uri = $this->web->uri;
    if (!strrpos($this->web->uri, '?')){
        $uri .= '?';
    } else {
        $uri .= '&';
    }
?>
<div class='filter'>
    <p class='filter_title'>Colors</p>

    <div class='colors'>
        <? foreach ($model->allColors as $color) { ?>
            <a href="<?=$uri.'color='.$color->id?>" class='color' style="background-image:url(<?=$color->getThumbnail();?>)" >
            </a>
        <? } ?>
    </div>

    <div class='active_colors'>
        <p class='filter_p'>Active colors</p>
        <div class='act_color'>
            //Here where I want the selected color thumbnail.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do another loop and print the thumbnails if they are selected.

```
<div class='filter'>
    <p class='filter_title'>Colors</p>

    <div class='colors'>
        <? foreach ($model->allColors as $color) { ?>
        <a href="<?= $uri.'color'.$color->id.'=1' ?>" class='color' style="background-image:url(<?= $color->getThumbnail(); ?>)" >
        </a>
        <? } ?>
    </div>

    <div class='active_colors'>
        <p class='filter_p'>Active colors</p>
        <div class='act_color'>
            //Here where I want the selected color thumbnail.
            <? foreach ($model->allColors as $color) : ?>
               <? if(isset($_GET['color'.$color->id] ): ?>
                  <a href="<?= $uri ?>" class='color' style="background-image:url(<?= $color->getThumbnail(); ?>)" ></a>
               <? endif; ?>
            <? endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. It worked. But when I select more than one color, active color shows the last selected color only. I think it's because: once selecting a colors, the url looks like : `www.abc.com/products?color=1&color=4&size=4.5`. I think we should get like: `www.abc.com/products?color=1%2C4&size=4.5%2C6` and then showing all the active colors. how can we do this ?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. One of them is to create a separate parameter for each color. See my updated answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What didn't work? Did you see an error message?

Comment: It worked later on. Thanks. I have one more question, if I want to reset those color filter, that is when user clicks that color on active filters, that color should be removed from `$_GET` option. How can I do that ?